# Unexpected %0A in URL results in file not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My file.php accept API calls from third party, but sometimes in the URL API call third party includes character `%0A`, which results into file not found.

normal call, which works:

```
example.com/file.php?text=SMS+123&id=22
```

wrong call - file not found (with `%0A` char):

```
example.com/file.php?text=SMS+123%0A&id=22
```

How can I rewrite that wrong call with `.htaccess`, that will redirect call to the same URL without `%0A` character in the URL?

//EDIT: Thank you all for replies! I found out the problem was in the apache security setting mod_security, which filtered inputs like this to prevent header injection by payload. Solution is to turn it off, or remove this specific condition.

Comment: the %0A is a linefeed, please bug your 3rd party app's developers that they don't do that, instead of a nasty workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It would arguably be preferable to sanitize the input in your PHP script, rather than `.htaccess`.

An *internal rewrite* would probably be preferable to an *external "redirect"* (as you appear to be suggesting), since the client making the request may not follow the redirect (depending on how the request is being made). And is there any benefit in making a round trip to the client - does the client need to know that the requested URL was not valid?

Assuming the `%0A` (URL encoded linefeed) can occur anywhere in the query string portion of the URL and this needs to be simply removed then you can do this using mod_rewrite near the top of your `.htaccess` file.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)%0A(.*)
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ $0?%1%2 [L]
```

The `QUERY_STRING` server variable is not %-decoded, so `%0A` can be matched literally.

The `$0` backreference matches the URL-path `file.php` - simply saves repetition. The `%1` and `%2` backreferences match the captured subpatterns from the preceding *CondPattern*, ie. before and after the troublesome `%0A`.